# How to make this in a nested ifelse statement

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

I am currently working on a project that requires the following: I want the port (a breed) to ask storage locations (another breed) whether they have a certain value. If not, that proceed to ask the next storage location etc. etc. until he finds that location with the correct value. If so, than it should take another action (like building something). I got this now, which seems to work but it is super long and over complicated I think.

```
to check-pipeline-26
  ask storage 26
  [ifelse pipeline < 1
    [build-pipeline]
    [check-pipeline-27]
  ]
end

to check-pipeline-27
  ask storage 27
  [ifelse pipeline < 1
    [build-pipeline]
    [check-pipeline-28]
  ]
end

to check-pipeline-28
  ask storage 28
  [ifelse pipeline < 1
    [build-pipeline]
    [check-pipeline-29]
  ]
end

to check-pipeline-29
  ask storage 29
  [ifelse pipeline < 1
    [build-pipeline]
    [check-pipeline-30]
  ]
end
```

Let me know if you have any tips to make this easier or simplified. Thanks in advance!

Max

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to go sequentially? If the `port` will eventually get to the `storage` with the correct value regardless, can you just use something like `ask one-of storages with [ pipeline < 1 ] [ build-pipeline ]` (untested, you may need to modify to fit your breeds etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution instead where I pass in the pipeline number as a parameter:

```
to check-pipeline [n]
    if n <= max [who] of storages
    ask storage n [ifelse pipeline < 1 
     [build-pipeline]
     [check-pipeline n + 1]
]
end
```

Note: you probably keep track of your max-who in a variable rather than computing each time.

Alternatively, this may be a better solution where you could just use a for loop and sort the agents by their who to make them go in order:

```
 to check-pipeline
     foreach sort-on  [who] storages
      [astorage -> ask astorage[ if pipeline < 1 [build-pipeline stop]]]
    ]
 end
```

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! Probably leads to the following problem where I did the same for 'build-pipeline', so gave each pipeline a different variable. But let me see if I can fix this!